# Abstracting a loop with a try/catch block around the loop body

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let us suppose, I have to loop a lot of collections to retrieve data. I want to enclose each iteration with a try/catch block to avoid premature exit from the loop in case of error. Example:

```
for(Object o : aCollection) {
   try {
         // possible exception is thrown here
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // write log             
     }
 }
```

However, I have a lot of loops in my code (for, enhanced for, while). Adding a try/catch block is error prone and makes the code less readable.

How can I add such a block to each loop without having to write a lot of boilerplate code?

Is there any pattern/framework that can be used?

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Why is your code throwing so many exceptions during normal operation in the first place?

Comment: You could use the strategy pattern. Java8 lambdas make this easy. (i.e. write a function void `loopTryCatch(List<T> l, Consumer<T> c)` and call it with `loopTryCatch(myListOfInt, (int i) -> System.out.println(i))`)

Comment: Be careful with try/catch in a `while` that you don't skip the code that would terminate the loop causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @5gon12eder We are using a legacy library and it's not under our control

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard thanks but we can only use java 5

Comment: Thanks @JamesMontagne but this is not the case

Comment: @user3337180 Ok, you can probably (not sure about Java 5) still do it without lambda expressions though -- it will just be much more verbose as you will have to use an anonymous inner class each time.

Comment: ***Adding a try/catch block is error prone** and **makes the code less readable*** Both these statements are not true. The try/catch itself is not error prone and try/catch statements are very readable.

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed version of my comment's suggestion to use a strategy pattern:

```
public static <T> void forTryCatch(Iterable<T> it, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    for (T t : it) {
        try {
            consumer.accept(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle e
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have Java8, you'll need to define Consumer:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}
```

and use it like so:

```
forTryCatch(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer t) {
        System.out.println(el);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this is quite verbose, so it probably isn't worth it unless you have a lot of additional code in `forTryCatch`.

In Java8, `Consumer` already exists and using the function is much shorter:

```
forTryCatch(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), el -> {
    System.out.println(el);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. It's a good example in any case. For sure, Java 8 would make it easier

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract the "for-with-try-catch" thing, but I wouldn't recommend it unless your abstraction does something more specific to your needs.

What you could do:

```
public class LoopUtils {

    public static <T> void doLoop(Collection<T> coll, Processor<T> proc){
        for(T t : coll){
            try {
                proc.process(t);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                proc.handleException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface Processor<T> {

    public void process(T t) throws Exception;

    public void handleException(Exception ex);

}
```

Usage:

```
Collection<MyClass> aCollection;

// ...

LoopUtils.doLoop(aCollection, new Processor<MyClass>() {

    public void process(MyClass t) throws Exception {
        // Do things...
    }

    public void handleException(Exception ex) {
        // Handle the exception
    }
});
```

Why it's not a good idea: it does not make the code any more readable, nor does it reduce duplication.

Abstractions are useful when they are (1) generic enough to be used in multiple places, and *at the same time* (2) concrete enough that they actually implement something not already implemented in the underlying language or platform. If condition 1 is not met you don't have an abstraction at all. If condition 2 is not met then you have an example of the [Inner-platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect): the abstraction does not provide any added value, while it does provide unnecessary limitations and opportunities for bugs to appear.

The code in this answer does not meet condition 2, since it is simply a bad replica of a try-catch block.

*However*, you should study the context in which you have so many loops. If all of them do similar things with the different collections, or all of them handle the exceptions in the same way, then some kind of abstraction might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This a good example but you are right, it's still too verbose.